# Snap.svg: drag() issue with default behavior of Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, snap.svg

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I've following two goals that I'm trying to achieve:

1. I need single line / multi line editable text input fields embedded in a SVG document.
2. These fields must have drag functionality.

The purpose of making text fields a part of SVG is to scale them when SVG document is scaled writing any excess code.

To accomplish these 2 tasks I'm using [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) library.

**What I've done so far:**

SVG has a [`foreignObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) element that allows us to embed any HTML Markup in SVG. So using this feature I've added `input` and `textarea` fields in SVG.

Below is a demo:

```js
var s = Snap('#demo');
var defualtWidth = s.attr('width');
var defualtHeight = s.attr('height');

var fobjectSVG = '<foreignObject x="30" y="40" width="240" height="40"><input type="text" class="form-control"placeholder="Some dummy text here..." /></foreignObject>';

s.append(Snap.parse(fobjectSVG));

$('.select-zoom').change(function(event) {
 var zoomRatio = $(this).val();

 s.attr({
  'width': defualtWidth * zoomRatio,
  'height': defualtHeight * zoomRatio
 });
});
```

```css
.form-control {
 border: 3px solid #000;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 background: #fff;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}

.select-zoom {
  position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
  right: 40px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="demo" width="700" height="550" viewBox="0 0 700 550">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="550" href="https://i.imgur.com/waDgcnc.jpg" />
</svg>
<select class="select-zoom">
  <option value="0.5">50%</option>
  <option value="0.75">75%</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">100%</option>
  <option value="1.25">125%</option>
  <option value="1.5">150%</option>
  <option value="2">200%</option>
  <option value="2.5">250%</option>
  <option value="5">500%</option>
</select>
```

**Adding drag feature:**

Snap.svg has a `.drag()` function that attaches drag functionality to an element when it is called.

Below is a demo:

```js
var s = Snap('#demo');
var rect = s.rect(30, 30, 240, 120).attr({stroke: '#000', 'strokeWidth': 3, fill: '#2ecc40'});
rect.drag();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="demo" width="700" height="550" viewBox="0 0 700 550">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="550" href="https://i.imgur.com/waDgcnc.jpg" />
</svg>
```

**What is the problem?**

When I call `.drag()` function on this `foreignObject`, `input` / `textarea` fields inside it stops their normal behavior. It seems that their default behavior is cancelled somehow.

Below is a demo of the problem:

```js
var s = Snap('#demo');
var defualtWidth = s.attr('width');
var defualtHeight = s.attr('height');

var fobjectSVG = '<foreignObject x="30" y="40" width="240" height="40"><input type="text" class="form-control"placeholder="Some dummy text here..." /></foreignObject>';

var fobjectSVG2 = '<foreignObject x="30" y="100" width="240" height="120"><textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "></textarea></foreignObject>';

var field = s.group().append(Snap.parse(fobjectSVG));
var field2 = s.group().append(Snap.parse(fobjectSVG2));
field.drag();
field2.drag();

$('.select-zoom').change(function(event) {
 var zoomRatio = $(this).val();

 s.attr({
  'width': defualtWidth * zoomRatio,
  'height': defualtHeight * zoomRatio
 });
});
```

```css
.form-control {
 border: 3px solid #000;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 background: #fff;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}

.select-zoom {
  position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
  right: 40px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="demo" width="700" height="550" viewBox="0 0 700 550">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="550" href="https://i.imgur.com/waDgcnc.jpg" />
</svg>
<select class="select-zoom">
  <option value="0.5">50%</option>
  <option value="0.75">75%</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">100%</option>
  <option value="1.25">125%</option>
  <option value="1.5">150%</option>
  <option value="2">200%</option>
  <option value="2.5">250%</option>
  <option value="5">500%</option>
</select>
```

As you can see in above demo, fields are dragging but I can't edit their text like for normal input / textarea fields.

**What is the question?**

I wants to enable their default behaior that is currently disabled somehow. Can someone explain why this is happening and how can I fix this issue?

All solutions are welcomed whether they belong to this library or some other.

**EDIT:**

Text selection of text fields can be disabled and is not needed in my case.

***Note:*** foreignObject is not supported by IE browsers so above example may not work if you are using IE. However it is
supported by MS Edge browser.

Comment: The problem I think is that Snaps drag has a preventDefault in there. However, getting around this may introduce a larger user interface issue. What you want to happen on a single mousedown/click. Do you want it to be part of the drag, or edit the textarea (and not part of the drag). Other drag handlers will probably have the same issue, as it's a user design issue maybe ?

Comment: @Ian On single click, user should be able to edit text inside fields. While he/she should be able to drag the field as well.

Comment: But to start a textarea edit, it's mousedown, not a single click. So either mousedown = textarea edit, or mousedown = start of drag. What happens if you want to drag over text in the textarea ? Maybe you can fudge something, but it will likely always be a fudge that's open to issues.

Comment: @Ian Ok, Is it somehow possible to achieve this? This is a requirement of the project I'm working on. I need to achieve it somehow. What do you think if I write some custom drag handler?

Comment: If you can explain the logic of what you want to happen on a mousedown that isn't in conflict with the other, it may be possible depending on that. However, it feels like the requirement of the project is possibly incorrect.

Comment: @Ian In my opinion, on `mouseup` event, input or textarea focus should be set. Field is actually dragged or not. It shouldn't matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139163/discussion-between-ian-and-muhammad-usman).

Answer (score 1):

Try a DIV in a foreignObject with contentEditable. Below is an example without Snap.drag(), but using standard svg drag methods:
Note: The Edge browser requires the foreignObject width/height=100%

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Drag foreignObject DIV</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style=background:gainsboro;width:300px;height:300px >
<svg id="mySVG" width="300" height="300"   onmouseup="endDrag()"   onmousemove="drag(evt)" >
<foreignObject id="dragTarget"  transform="translate(24 40)" width="100%" height="100%"><div id=myDiv onmousedown="startDrag();this.contentEditable='false'" style='border:2px solid black;width:150px;height:50px;overflow:auto' contentEditable="true" >This is my text</div></foreignObject>
</svg>
</div>
<script>
var TransformRequestObj
var TransList
var DragTarget=null;
var Dragging = false;
var DragStartGrabX = 0;
var DragStartGrabY = 0;
//---mouse down over element---
function startDrag()
{
 if(!Dragging) //---prevents dragging conflicts on other draggable elements---
 {

   DragTarget = document.getElementById("dragTarget")

   //---reference point to its respective viewport--
   var pnt = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
   pnt.x = event.clientX
   pnt.y = event.clientY
   //---elements transformed and/or in different(svg) viewports---
   var sCTM = DragTarget.getScreenCTM();
   var Pnt = pnt.matrixTransform(sCTM.inverse());

   TransformRequestObj = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGTransform()
   //---attach new or existing transform to element, init its transform list---
   var myTransListAnim=DragTarget.transform
   TransList=myTransListAnim.baseVal
            //---the point on the element to grab as its dragging point---
   DragStartGrabX = Pnt.x
   DragStartGrabY = Pnt.y

   Dragging=true;

 }
}
//---mouse move---
function drag(evt)
{
 if(Dragging)
 {
  var pnt = DragTarget.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint();
  pnt.x = evt.clientX;
  pnt.y = evt.clientY;
  //---elements in different(svg) viewports, and/or transformed ---
  var sCTM = DragTarget.getScreenCTM();
  var Pnt = pnt.matrixTransform(sCTM.inverse());
  Pnt.x -= DragStartGrabX;
  Pnt.y -= DragStartGrabY;

  TransformRequestObj.setTranslate(Pnt.x,Pnt.y)
  TransList.appendItem(TransformRequestObj)
  TransList.consolidate()
 }
}
//--mouse up---
function endDrag()
{
 Dragging = false ;
    myDiv.contentEditable="true"
   
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```